# Git branch, checkout and merge, trying to understand the use of it

Tags: git, github, version-control

As an unexperienced git user I'm trying to understand why using a new branch in your local repository and merge it with master when the changes are ready. Is my assumption right that this is particularly usefull when you want to push the master branch to the remote repository after you've finished your local work and you get the message that your master branch is 'outdated'? In other words:

1. git clone the repo to my local machine
2. git branch new_branch
3. git checkout new_branch
4. after I finished my work in new_branch: git checkout master
5. git merge new_branch
6. git push to the remote repo
7. Message that your work is behind, because somebody else made changes after I cloned the repo
8. git pull; now my local master branch is up to date
9. git merge new_branch
10. git push to the remote repo
11. when it's ok, I can remove my local new_branch

Is my thinking right? Is my point 7 the main reason why you should always make your changes in a newly created local branch and not in your local master branch? So the new local branch serves as a backup of your changes which you can merge again with the master branch?

Hope it's explained clear enough.

Thx,
Luc

Comment: The main reason to use branches is to keep separate things (think of tickets, ideas, fixes, improvements) separate. You merge into more _meaningful_ branches (like develop, main, etc) when you consider that a given feature/bugfix/etc is _ready_. This is so that you can easily move around without having to worry to commit stuff that is only half-way cooked.

Comment: ... _and_ this doesn't require pushing anywhere. I have many projects that I keep only locally and I use more than one branch to develop stuff, normally.

Answer (score 3):

> As an unexperienced git user I'm trying to understand why using a new branch in your local repository and merge it with master when the changes are ready.

It's all about keeping master as a stable baseline for work, and to reduce complexity by keeping separate things separated. That could be between you and other people, or you and yourself. So much of programming is about not letting things get tangled together.

What if suddenly you have to work on TWO things? A pressing bug appears, or your boss sets a new priority, or you realize your work would go a lot easier if you did something else first, or you just get distracted. If you've been committing to master, they have to be all tangled together making everything more complicated and error prone. If you're working in branches, you switch between branches.

What if after making six commits you realize that thing isn't such a good idea? If you've been committing to master, you have to revert all that change and hopefully you get all of it! If you're working in branches, you delete the branch.

If you're using a review process, you will often be waiting around for a set of changes to be reviewed. It would be good to be able to start on the next task. If you've been working on master, you'll have to work on top of unreviewed code which might change. What if the review finds problems? Now you're mixing up fixes for the first task with unfinished work on the second.

Nothing goes into master until it's reviewed, tested, and complete. This ensures master is a stable platform for more work for you and everyone else working on the project.

For more detail about the basics of a branched process see [Git Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow).

---

Your specific workflow has a flaw. You don't need to remerge after you pull.

- git branch new_branch
- git checkout new_branch

  - This can be combined as `git checkout -b new_branch`
- after I finished my work in new_branch: git checkout master
- git merge new_branch
- git push to the remote repo
- Message that your work is behind, because somebody else made changes after I cloned the repo

If there's multiple people working on the repo, there should be a review step before you merge. This gets more eyes on the code, more people aware of what you're doing, and prevents people from going off on tangents.

On Github these are [Pull Requests](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests).

The merge is done on the "server" so you pull the new master immediately.

- git pull; now my local master branch is up to date
- <strike>git merge new_branch</strike>

That extra merge is the major mistake. Your branch has already been merged into master locally. `git pull` does not wipe this out, it merges the remote master with your local master. This includes your merged branch.

- git push to the remote repo
- <strike>when it's ok, I can remove my local new_branch</strike>

In this workflow, because you have no review step, pushing and pulling are mostly irrelevant to the branching/merge process. You're doing the integration yourself. You can delete the branch as soon as you merge.

---

Here's the basic solo workflow.

- Work.
- Update.
- Test.
- Merge.
- Share.

And in more detail.

- Work.

  - git checkout -b feature
  - Make small, focused commits each doing a single thing.
- Update

  - Do this as often as you'd like to keep from falling behind.
  - Update master

    - git checkout master
    - git pull
  - Update feature

    - git checkout feature
    - git merge master
- Test

  - Test as often as you like, probably more than you'd like.
- Merge

  - Feature is complete, tested, and up to date.
  - git checkout master
  - git merge feature
  - git branch -d feature
- Share.

  - git push

Its good to ensure the work is fully finished before inflicting it on others. *Only after your work is complete and up to date do you push*.

This covers the basics. There are many ways to streamline and improve this workflow. Even when working solo, consider using Github pull requests or the equivalent in whatever system you're using.